# Finding the area formed by reflection of $x+\sin x$ about the line $x+y=0$

Tags: calculus, area

Let $y=g(x)$ be the reflection of $f(x)=x+\sin x$ about the line $x+y=0$.If the area bounded by $y=g(x)$, $x$-axis, $x=0$ and $x=2\pi$ is $A$. The question is to evaluate $A$.

I noticed that $f(x)$ is non-negative. Also the area bounded by the reflection of $f(x)$ is same as area bounded by $f^{-1} x$ So the area is
$$\int_0^{2\pi} 2(x-f(x))+f(x) dx$$
which evaluates to $2\pi^2$. However I would like to know any other method to do this more quickly and elegantly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Note that the curve that bounds the region in question from above is symmetric about $(\pi,\pi)$ and passes through opposite corners of a square of side length $2\pi$. $A$ is thus half of the square's area, or $\frac{(2\pi)^2}2=2\pi^2$.

Answer (score 1):

if reflection of $f(x)$ over $(y=-x)$ is $g(y)$ in the interval $(0,2\pi)$

then $g(y) = -y+sin(-y) = -(y+sin (y))$ in the interval $(0,2\pi)$

Now the area under the curve $g(y)$ is A $$= \int_{0}^{2\pi} g(y).(-dy) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} (y+sin(y))dy = \frac{y^2}{2} + cos(y)|_{0}^{2\pi}$$
$$ = \frac{(2\pi)^{2}}{2} + cos(2\pi) - cos(0) = 2\pi^2 +1-1 = 2\pi^2$$